# In configuration of 'Protractor' in 'Eclipse' IDE, 'Convert to tern' project option click, it is not displaying 'Modules' pop up window?

Tags: eclipse, protractor

I followed below link to configure 'Protractor' in 'Eclipse' IDE

https://seleniuminterview.com/protractor-setup-with-eclipse/

I installed:

1. 'Node.js'
2. 'Protractor'
3. 'Webdriver-manager' tool
4. Verified 'Selenium server' status at http://localhost:4444 it is working fine
5. In 'Eclipse Market place' installed 'AngularJS' plug in
6. Created 'JavaScript project'
7. Created 'conf.js', 'example_spec.js' files
8. Clicked on 'convert to tern' project option by right clicking the 'JavaScript' project

After clicking on 'Convert to Tern' project option it is not displaying 'Modules' window?

Answer (score 0):

After `step7`,

Open command prompt and navigate to your java script directory and execute command :- `npm install protractor` (this command will load node_modules folder inside your project directory)

Then continue with other steps.

Hope it helps you

If it fails,then try the steps from https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/Protractor

Comment: 1. After execution of 'npm install protractor' command , 'Node_modules' folder is created in the 'Java script' project 2. Now i clicked on 'Convert to tern' project option , now the 'Node_modules -> Protractor' folder is displaying 'Error' symbol and in 'Console' it is displaying ',' expected in actions_test.js file  /Protractor Project/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/test

Comment: In 'Global Preferences' pop up(Window -> Preferences) i couldn't see 'Protractor' option under 'Angular Js'. It is displaying only 'HTML' option.

Comment: @VasundharaPakkurthi I made it by following https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/Protractor. It should definitely help you.